# For loop in Python In Sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone tell me how I can loop through these places and not have it list it down by continue with the string as attached to the string.

```
world = ["Japan", "China", "Seattle", "Brazil"]

print "This is my story of the following places: " 

for place in world:
    print place
```

**EDIT:** I put a comma at the end of the print command however since its a separated list I would prefer if I was able to add a separator.
End result I want it to show like:

```
This is my store of the following places. Japan, China, Seattle, Brazil.
```

**Final Edit:** With the following code it drops off a line and I'm trying to find out how to remove the additional line so that it continues on the same line.

```
world = ["Japan", "China", "Seattle", "Brazil"]


print "This is my story of the following places: ", 

for i in range(0,len(world)):
    if i==(len(world)-1):
        print world[i] + '.'
    else:
        print world[i] +',',

print ". Which has all
```

This is the story of the following places I visited. They are China, Japan, Seattle, and Brazil

. Which has all of the great icons fo

Comment: I'm having a really hard time grokking your question. Can you rephrase? It would also be helpful to have some sample data for `world`, current output, and desired output.

Comment: `NameError`, `world` is not defined.

Comment: Editted with places.

Comment: Oh! You want to not print newlines?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Comment: I'm taking a new class Beth Crane and this is my first chance with Python and in a stand still because I"m not understanding any of those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a comma after the `print()` command to prevent new lines:

**In response to your comment:**

```
world = ["Japan", "China", "Seattle", "Brazil"]


print "This is my story of the following places: ", 

for i in range(0,len(world)):
    if i==(len(world)-1):
        print world[i] + '.', #<-- Add another comma
    else:
        print world[i] +',',
```

This outputs:

```
This is my story of the following places:  Japan, China, Seattle, Brazil.
```

I made the if-statement to add 'commas' and a 'period' to make the output look like a list. This would work with ANY size list.

However, take a look at the `join()` method (suggested by @ILostMySpoon). It is much more efficient.

Comment: I did but I have to have a for loop in my homework so I didn't know how i could have that and apply the join into the string.

Comment: @user3732216 Its more efficient because it _doesn't_  use a for-loop. You can just use mine for your homework. I made my solution to fit your needs, however, in practice, I would always choose the more efficient alternative.

Comment: I only have one more issue with this. I'll comment one last time on my initial post and then I'll award you the check mark.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `join()` method to take a list of things to join with a given string

```
print "This is my store of the following places. " + ", ".join(world)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is program for python that I modified so you can calculate the multiplicative inverse for a whole set from 0 to "m":

```
#This code was edited by David Pinos from cybersecurity Centennial College. Canada
# This code is contributed by Nikita tiwari and it was taked from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/#:~:text=To%20find%20multiplicative%20inverse%20of,value%20of%20gcd%20as%201.&text=We%20can%20remove%20the%20second,0%20for%20an%20integer%20y.

# Iterative Python 3 program to find 
# modular inverse using extended 
# Euclid algorithm 
  
# Returns modulo inverse of a with 
# respect to m using extended Euclid 
# Algorithm Assumption: a and m are 
# coprimes, i.e., gcd(a, m) = 1 
def modInverse(a, m) : 
    m0 = m 
    y = 0
    x = 1
  
    if (m == 1) : 
        return 0
  
    while (a > 1) : 
  
        # q is quotient 
        if (m==0):
            return "there is no inverse for this number"
        else:
            q = a // m 
            t = m 
  
            # m is remainder now, process 
            # same as Euclid's algo 
            m = a % m 
            a = t 
            t = y 
  
            # Update x and y 
            y = x - q * y 
            x = t 
    # Make x positive 
    if (x < 0) : 
        x = x + m0 
    return x 
  
  
# Driver program to test above function 

m = 26 #your SET

i=0
while (i<m):
    print("Modular multiplicative inverse of ", i, " in ", m, " is: ", modInverse(i, m))
    i=i+1
```